# what means "add method to prototype"

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, constructor, prototype

For instance, we already have 3 "classes" (functions):
Fruit <= Apple <= GreenApple. So Apple inheriting from Fruit and GreenApple inheriting from Apple. (using prototypes on instances).
So if I understand correctly: "fruit.prototype" is an Object, "apple.prototype" is a Fruit and "greenApple.prototype" is an "Apple"?
So, taking this into account, I have following question:

what means "Apple.prototype" in "Apple.prototype.getInfo"???:

```
function Apple (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
}

Apple.prototype.getInfo = function() {
    return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
};
```

Again: for me, Apple's prototype is a Fruit (Apple.prototype == Fruit), but in the code above we see that it uses another way so what is Apple.prototype here ???
If we get new instance of Apple.

```
var greenApple = new GreenApple('apple1');
```

and if there are no getInfo method in GreenApple class, it'll be look at greenApple.prototype (Apple), but getInfo declared in Apple.prototype (what is it)??

Finally:
What difference between:

```
Apple.prototype.getInfo = function(){*_*}
```

and

```
Apple.getInfo = function() {*_*}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Apple's prototype is a Fruit (Apple.prototype == Fruit)

No. "Apple's prototype is ***a*** Fruit" doesn't mean "Apple's prototype is Fruit"

The former means means

```
Apple.prototype instanceof Fruit
```

The latter means

```
Apple.prototype === Fruit
```

Comment: yeah, there are just syntaxis mistake, but again: If we get new instance of Apple.

    var greenApple = new GreenApple('apple1');
which class inheriting from Apple class

and if there are no "getInfo" method in GreenApple class, it'll look at greenApple.prototype (Apple), but getInfo declared in **Apple.prototype** (what is it)??

Comment: No. `greenApple.prototype` is an instance of `Apple`, not `Apple` itself. So it's just an object, possibly with some methods or properties, which inherits from `Apple.prototype`.

Comment: but how can it inheriting from `Apple.prototype`, whereas `Apple.prototype === Fruit` ? I thought it inheriting directly from `Apple`. So therein lies my question: **what is `Apple.prototype` exactly? Is it `Fruit` or something else?**

Comment: No. `Apple.prototype !== Fruit`. It's something else. `Apple.prototype instanceof Fruit`.

Comment: What difference between:

    `Apple.prototype.getInfo = function(){*_*} `
and
    
    `Apple.getInfo = function() {*_*}`
in 1st case I add function to Apple's value "prototype" and its instances will not take new memory while inintialize, they look in Apple.prototype, right? so `apple.prototype` and `Apple.prototype` isn't the same?

Comment: `Apple.prototype.getInfo` will be a prototypical method available on all `Apple` instances via inheritance. `Apple.getInfo` will be a static method of the constructor, not available on instances. I don't know what `apple` is.

Comment: thank you!) PS: if you have time, can you shed some light on essense "prototypical method" so this is the constructor's prototype which is unique for each instance, right?

Comment: The constructor's `prototype` is shared among all instances. That's why you can add a method to it and it will become available on all instances.